# Show a specific element with specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<nav id="sales-countries">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">...1...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...2...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...3...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...4...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...5...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...6...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...7...</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="sales-location">...1...</nav>
<nav class="sales-location">...2...</nav>
<nav class="sales-location">...3...</nav>
<nav class="sales-location">...4...</nav>
<nav class="sales-location">...5...</nav>
<nav class="sales-location">...6...</nav>
<nav class="sales-location">...7...</nav>
```

Javascript:

```
$("nav.sales-location").hide();

$("#sales-countries a:eq(0)").click(function() {
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();
  $("nav.sales-location:eq(0)").show();
});

$("#sales-countries a:eq(1)").click(function() {
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();
  $("nav.sales-location:eq(1)").show();
});

$("#sales-countries a:eq(2)").click(function() {
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();
  $("nav.sales-location:eq(2)").show();
});

$("#sales-countries a:eq(3)").click(function() {
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();
  $("nav.sales-location:eq(3)").show();
});

$("#sales-countries a:eq(4)").click(function() {
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();
  $("nav.sales-location:eq(4)").show();
});

$("#sales-countries a:eq(5)").click(function() {
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();
  $("nav.sales-location:eq(5)").show();
});

$("#sales-countries a:eq(6)").click(function() {
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();
  $("nav.sales-location:eq(6)").show();
});
```

I need, that element of specific number - button, show an element of specific number.

JavaScript code above have this property and work well, but it is too long.

How I make this property for (for example) one hundred buttons and elements for showing so that JavaScript code was very short?

Between code paragraphs is different in the two numbers only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by a common function for every li click and you can show corresponding div by jquery  [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

try this:

```
$("nav.sales-location").hide();

$("#sales-countries ul li").click(function() {
    ind = $(this).index();//get the li index
  $("nav.sales-location").hide();// hide all divs
  $("nav.sales-location:eq("+ind+")").show(); //show corresponding index div
});
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/685/)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce it to just:

```
$("nav.sales-location").hide();
$("#sales-countries a").click(function() {
    $("nav.sales-location").hide();
    $("nav.sales-location:eq("+$(this).index('#sales-countries a')+")").show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pFE4U/)**

You can pass a selector to [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to specify what collection it's relative to.

Answer (score 0):

since you're just showing the same text as the `a` that's clicked you can grab the value using `.text()` and pass it to an empty div called `.sales-location`

```
$("#sales-countries a").click(function() {
  var results = $(this).text();
  $(".sales-location").html(results);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RA8m8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $locations = $("nav.sales-location").hide();

$("#sales-countries a").click(function () {
    $locations.hide().filter(":eq(" + $(this).parent().index() + ")").show();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bZLqR/1/

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this kind of recently. This will do it even with Jquery.

```
var array = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]
var list = document.getElementById('some-id');

function links(){  // generate links
    for (var i in array){
        var val = array[i];
        var li = document.createELement('li');
        li.innerHTML = "<a href='#'>" + val + "</a>"
        li.onclick = show;
        li.index = i;  // save the array index for later
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}

function show(e){
    var index = e.target.index || -1 ;
    var toShow = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name');
    // hide all
    for (var i  in toShow){
        toShow[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    // show the one I want.
    if (toShow.length < index && index >= 0){
        toShow[index].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}

links(); // build the links.
```